# When i am at this specific component called homeb i don't want the header or nav to show up. But now i have added a parameter and the nav does show up

Tags: angular

<app-nav *ngIf="router.url !== '/homeb'">

http://localhost:4200/homeb/19331 this is homeb with the parameter and now the nav or header does show up.
How can i hide it for this specific url?
the paramter changes from 19331 to a different one.

Comment: I think you have add here id also like this: `<app-nav *ngIf="router.url !== '/homeb/:id'">` .

Comment: i have used that but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't test for strict  equality of you've got parameters in the url

```
<app-nav *ngIf="router.url.indexOf('/homeb') < 0">
```